# removing empty lines using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have an interesting string I want to properly break up into a string array. This string is as follows.

```
String test="?[32,120],x1y1,[object pieceP1],null]";
```

Now I have this regular expression to attack this.

```
String delims = "[?,\\[\\]]";
```

Now the results of splitting it using this code

```
String[] tokens = mapString.split(delims);
```

yields this result

-->
-->
32
120
-->
x1y1
-->
object pieceP1
-->
null

where the arrows are the empty lines.

How can I modify this regular expression so that there are no empty lines?

Thank you greatly in advance.

~ Selcuk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String delims = "[?,\\[\\]]+";`  // []+

[see the **Greedy quantifiers** part in **Summary of regular-expression constructs** of Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

but the leading empty element is still there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Google Guava's `Splitter` class to facilitate that: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

`Splitter.omitEmptyStrings()` should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class Regex 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String []split = "?[32,120],x1y1,[object pieceP1],null]".split("([?,\\[\\]])+");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("'"+split[i]+"'");
        }
    }
}
```

If your test string starts with a delimiter then the index 0 of the array will always be an empty string. You can put a check for it like this `if(split[0].length == 0) continue;`

**`>>Output`**

```
''
'32'
'120'
'x1y1'
'object pieceP1'
'null'
```